# Personal.xlsb workbook is non-existent. I've looked everywhere! Any new ideas? Can I just create one?

Tags: excel, vba

I've never been able to find the Personal.xlsb workbook. I've looked in the XLStart folder, it does not show in my VBA project explorer, and I don't know what to do. I went into my C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART
folder and just made a dummy xlsb. Can anyone think of any negative consequences to having this?

I honestly just need a spot to store all my macros for easy referencing, as I currently just put them in workbooks I need them to work, and then back them up in some text file somewhere in a pretty rudimentary list. Any advice on that would also be nice.

Best,
George

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-how-Excel-starts-6509b9af-2cc8-4fb6-9ef5-cf5f1d292c19#bm1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just create it.  As far as I know there are no negative consequences for doing so, as long as you:
 - call the file `Personal.xlsb`
 - put it in the Excel Startup path (which you can find by executing `? Application.StartupPath` from the Immediate pane in VBA editor) - usually this would be the path you mention
 - hide the file (View tab, Hide command)

You can alternatively get Excel to automatically create the file in the right place with the right name etc by just recording a dummy macro using the macro recorder and choosing to Store macro in: "Personal Macro Workbook".

Comment: I tried calling it Personal.xlsb and when I created a button in the quick access toolbar using one of the stored macros in it, it did not work properly when the function macro was called in other workbooks.

Also, Personal Macro Workbook was not listed as an option. Currently, reinstalling MSO. :'(

Answer (score 0):

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-your-macros-to-a-Personal-Macro-Workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566

You can go to the tab 'View' in your ribbon. You click on 'unhide'.
There you should be able to unhide Personal.xlsb
If it's not there, it doesn't exist.